# Can Microsoft.Contracts' static checker be used without Team System?

Tags: .net, design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

Aside from the requirement on Visual Studio Team System to be able to install Microsoft.Contacts with the static checker,  is it possible to run the static checker without team system?  Or, does it depend on an API exposed by studio's team system components?

Also, is it within the license to copy the static checker from a computer with team system to one with professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can currently [get it under an academic licence](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/4ed7dd5f-490b-489e-8ca8-109324279968/default.aspx), but I personally expect that the version integrated with .NET 4.0 and VS2010 will *only* be available under team system. Darned shame IMO, but such is life :( While you might technically be *able* to copy the checker from a VSTS system to a Pro system, I expect that would break the licence conditions.

(Aside from anything else, it means I'll have to download the VSTS version of beta 2 when that comes out, just to check what it all looks like for the book... I'll install in a VM to avoid polluting my laptop's Pro installation.)

Comment: That would be a damned shame if they only allowed it in TS in .NET 4.  I was actually looking to use it on an express edition.  Too bad that is unavailable.  If you are very familiar with Microsoft.Contracts, could you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215054/

Comment: I saw that question yesterday, but without current access to the checker, I can't experiment :(

Comment: Well, yeah I was asking because we have team system at work, but I don't have it at home.  Maybe I should get technet.